# Angular2 local storage Subject()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subject

I will explain you my (probably little) problem :)

I'm trying to make a localStorage which set and get some data (array of object).
I have one component which add object in my local storage array and one other which get this data.

I'm on ionic2 tabs app, and when I set my local storage, my other view where I get this it's not update...

I think I have to use a RxJs Subject but I don't know how do this properly.

Have a look on my current code

```
// LocalStorageService.ts

export class LocalStorageService {
  public bookmarks: Subject<any> = new Subject()

  constructor (public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}


  setUserBookmarks(bookmarks: any) {
    localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    this.bookmarks.next(bookmarks)
  }

  getUserBookmarks() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myData"))
  }
```

Then, my components

```
// Component where I set data

export class ListEventsComponent {

 bookmarks: any

 constructor(private navParams: NavParams, 
 private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.localStorageService.bookmarks.subscribe(bookmarks => {
    this.bookmarks = bookmarks
  })
 }


 bookmark(event) {
  this.localStorageService.setUserBookmarks(event)
 }
}
```

and the last:

```
// Component where I get data

export class AboutPage {
 public bookmarks: any

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private   localStorageService:LocalStorageService) {
   this.localStorageService.bookmarks.subscribe(bookmarks => {
     this.bookmarks = bookmarks
     console.log(bookmarks)
   })
 }

 removeBookmark(eventID: string) {
   this.localStorageService.removeUserBookmark(this.bookmarks, eventID)
 }
}
```

So, how can I update my second component when I set in the first ?
Thank you in advance, if I'm not clear, don't hesitate to say it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your second component subscribe after the first is calling next, so he does not get any data. For this case you should use the [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) to get the latest emitted value:

```
 public bookmarks: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]); // The initial value
```

Comment: Your are welcome :) don't forget to accept the answer please.